# Is important to set 'var = null' in the end of lexical scope?

Tags: javascript

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) that clarified almost everything about scopes, leaving only this doubt:

If lexical scopes generate a new environment on each run and store their information, in an environment where code runs frequently, you need to declare `var_of_scope = null` at the end of the scope to free memory or JavaScript recognizes this automatically if not are there elements that refer to the environment?

Comment: I don't think that would be necessary. The scope will be automatically garbage collected as long as it's not referenced by anyone. Please let me know if you want more details. I can share some examples.

Comment: [MDN Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#mark-and-sweep_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

No, that is almost never necessary.

Javascript uses garbage collection. When no values in any scope reference a value stored in memory, it is removed during the next run of garbage collector.

In the situation you describe:

```
function foo() {
  let data = "some data here"
  // do stuff with data
  data = null
}
```

Setting the `null` here is not helpful. It does remove all references the previous value of `data`, but since the scope will end when the function ends, all local variables will be discarded along with it anyway.

---

In fact, this would prevent you from using the `const` keyword, which is a very very good thing to use. All your variables should be `const` by default, and you should change them to `let` only if you really need to assign them after initialization.

This is better:

```
function foo() {
  const data = "some data here"
  // do stuff with data
}
```

---

In general, you just don't have to worry about this. It's not easy to leak memory in javascript like it is in a language like C. [It's possible](https://www.ditdot.hr/en/causes-of-memory-leaks-in-javascript-and-how-to-avoid-them) but as long your following most best practices you'll probably be fine.